# What does this usage of "other" imply here?

Tags: interpretation

The setting is an unnamed though obviously New Yorkish high-rise city, the time less convincingly future than deliciously other, as it combines 21st-century engineering feats with 19th-century pork-barrel politics and smoky working-class pubs. [Source](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007YUBCM4)

What does this "other" mean here?

What does this whole section mean, and what does this sort of writing suggest?

Comment: This string of words is comprehensible, but it would be a lot better if you included the complete sentence (or paragraph!) and explained that it was from a book review.

Answer (score 1):

In case it's not obvious, I'll just point out that in the phrase...

> *the time [**is**] less convincingly **future** than deliciously **other***

...the word ***is*** has been [elided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29) (it's just an optional repetition of *"The setting **is**"*). We can recast the context into the simplified statement...

> *The time is **more other than future**.*

If you look at these written instances of [*was more other than*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20never%20went%20there%20before%20I%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22was%20more%20other%20than%22&tbm=bks), you'll see that (1) - it's not a common construction, and (2) - the word *"**other**"* is often enclosed in quote marks. Here's a typical usage...

> *Valerie is every inch a Californian—outgoing, bubbly, and liberal. So at the National Trust she was very **"other."***

---

In both OP's and my own example, ***other*** is simply an unusual and somewhat "literary" word-choice in contexts where most native speakers would use ***different***.

In all such usages, the precise nature of the difference is context-specific. In OP's case, the writer is saying the fictional work under review is set in a period that's different to the one we currently live in, because it contains an unusual combination of elements from the past, present, and foreseeable future.

---

I wouldn't advise learners to copy such obscure literary phrasing. There's nothing wrong with OP's example, but I would just say that in many similar contexts (not this one) it would probably be better to use more explicitly adjectival terms such as ***other-wordly, futuristic*** rather than plain ***other, future***.

Comment: I still wonder what *deliciously* is doing in there? Without it, I can understand that part, but with *deliciously*, I'm uncertain.

Comment: @Damkerng: He just means it's an *interesting, stimulating, appealing* kind of "difference", rather than something *unsettling, disconcerting, unpleasant* (which on average is the more common connotation of words like *other, strange, different*).

Comment: @kih1930: Well, obviously it's not *really* "futuristic", because it includes *19th-century pork-barrel politics and smoky working-class pubs*. It's just "strange".

Comment: But where's the definition in the dictionary?

Comment: @birdman: Per my final paragraph, and as implied by preceding text, it's *an unusual and somewhat "literary" word-choice* in this context. The Q&A here will get few votes because it's largely irrelevant to people who would need a dictionary to understand the exact meaning (i.e. - "learners"). Effectively, it's [M-W's definition #5](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/other) *- disturbingly or threateningly different* creatively converted to a "positive" attribute by the writer's (also literary/unusual) use of the word ***deliciously***.